# Python: find types of keys in locals()

Tags: python, introspection

`locals()` is a dict.  If I do a simple:

```
for i in locals().keys():
     type(i)
```

...what's returned is that the names are all strings (yes, in point of fact, they are) but those keys indicate different types - one might be, say, a module.  Some reference types (objects) but also primitive types (e.g. int, string).

In some sense, I want to extract the name from the string.  Looked at how to do this with the attributes on a string but no go.  I believe I need something from introspection, but what?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`locals().keys()` returns all the variable names bound in local space.  Since they are names, they are all strings.  (In Python 2.x you could use `locals().iterkeys()` for this also, to get an iterator.)

Try `locals().values()` instead.  For Python 2.x, you can use `locals().itervalues()` to get an iterator.

Or `locals().items()` to get `key, value` pairs.  For Python 2.x you can use `locals().iteritems()` to get an iterator.

Comment: Or `locals().items()` to get both name and value (handy if you want to print by the name and the type).

Comment: thanks - locals().values() did the trick and so I learned a new thing or two in the process.

Comment: Hi. Pycharm tells me that 'Code compability inspection' is worried about locals().iteritems(). Any ideas for fix?